# Implementing the builder pattern

Tags: java, builder

I have seen two popular methods of implementing the builder pattern:

```
// 1. The build() approach
Product p = builder.part1()
                   .part2()
                   .build();

// 2.The constructor approach
builder.part1()
       .part2();
Product p = new Product(builder);
```

Which of these is preferable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1st one is the way to go...

if you use the 2nd choice then doing this:

```
Product p = new Product(builder);
```

will add dependencies to the Product class..

that means the Product class needs now at least a constructor with the parameter **builder**

Comment: I also just realized that the 2. approach won't work if `Product` is an interface. You would have to introduce a method `construct()`, meaning you could just aswell go the `Builder.build()` route.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little vague, however in case you have a static builder class, effective java book of joshua bloch suggests a structure more like the first one with build method. It is a cleaner and safer way.

```
Product p= new Product.ProductBuilder("hw", "sw")
    .version(30)
    .mac("1234567")
    .address("Fake address 1234")
    .build();
```

Comment: I just googled for Josh Blochs implementation and i really like this one!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a combination of both of those examples.

I would define a builder class inside the Product class and give the product class a private constructor that takes a ProductBuilder.

Comment: Wouldn't accessing the internals of the `Product` be enough, if you make the builder an inner class?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I like to keep the state of the builder separate to the objects you are creating with it so once you build the object the builder can no longer modify it.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different approaches. Trades-off are different.
You must use and adapt a pattern according your needs and your context, not according a hard rule...

Using a builder like it :

```
Product p = new Product(builder);
```

allows to create your builder and to reuse it.
If you need to reuse the builder or to create the builder in another class, it is a good implementation. You open your API because you need it.
The drawbacks of the solution are a no straight way of creating your object.
About design quality and dependency, I think that it is a false problem.
Yes with a public constructor for Product, you create a public dependency between Product and builder and you expose the Product constructor.
But if in the Product constructor, you dispatch to the builder instance the task for constructing the Product, is the coupling will make the code less flexible ? Never.
 Besides, the real coupling is located in the Product construction since the builder uses mirrors properties to build the Product object. So, the real and strong coupling  will stay whatever happens: these two classes must work together and must look like.

Using a builder like it :

```
Product p = builder.part1()
               .part2()
               .build();
```

doesn't allow to reuse builder but is more straight to use for your client of the class and it opens at the minimum the dependency between Builder to Product. 
If you don't need to reuse the builder or to create the builder in another class, it's the best since you don't open your API in a useless way.

So, in the facts, both solutions are near.
I would use the solution with a constructor if I must reuse the builder or i need to create the builder in another class and i would use the solution without constructor if not needed.